# How does Zend\Db in ZF2 control transactions?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, zend-framework2, zend-db

The ZF1 Zend_Db reference manual has an [entire section](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.transactions) on performing transactions.

The [ZF2 Zend\Db reference manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.db.adapter.html) lacks any documentation on transactions.

How do I perform transactions in ZF2?  Example code would be helpful.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The missing documentation is curious.

To find out what happened, I had to dive into the [API docs](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.0/namespaces/Zend.Db.Adapter.html) for Zend\Db\Adapter.

It looks like `beginTransaction`, `rollback` and `commit` are defined in [Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\ConnectionInterface](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.0/classes/Zend.Db.Adapter.Driver.ConnectionInterface.html).  This means that they are methods callable on every single adapter connection.  Unfortunately the connection itself is rather buried.

What I'm not clear on -- and can't provide an example for at this time -- is figuring out which object you actually call these methods on.  In the worst case, it looks like you might want to call `$adapter->getDriver()->getConnection()->beginTransaction()`.

*Eww.*

I'm hoping someone else with more knowledge, and a copy of ZF2 handy, will see this and provide a better option.

Don't forget that you can just issue `BEGIN TRANSACTION`/`ROLLBACK`/`COMMIT`/`SET autocommit=...` SQL statements yourself.  This is *probably* OK, as it doesn't look like Zend\Db keeps track of the transaction state.

Comment: Many thanks Charles - I will need to go and read carefully through the API, on your final point to issue these directly would I work through PDO to do this.

Answer (score 41):

You've got it. The proper way to Begin, Commit, and Rollback Transactions is as follows:

```
$this->getAdapter()->getDriver()->getConnection()->beginTransaction();

$this->getAdapter()->getDriver()->getConnection()->commit();

$this->getAdapter()->getDriver()->getConnection()->rollback();
```

Just to put this out there too you can also get the Last ID created by:

```
$this->getAdapter()->getDriver()->getConnection()->getLastGeneratedValue()
```

If you are using pgSQL you will need to add the sequence to return the Last ID created:

```
$this->getAdapter()->getDriver()->getConnection()->getLastGeneratedValue('mail_mailid_seq')
```

Comment: This great, well-explained, many thanks!! The documents of ZF2 and ZF3 are not clear about this part!

Comment: is it true that getAdapter()->getDriver()->getConnection() creates a new db connection?

Answer (score 8):

There are two matter for doing transaction.
1 - MyISAM is not a transactional engine , so change tables engine to InnoDB.
2 - Transaction query(`"START TRANSACTION;"` OR `"ROLLBACK;"`) connection must be same with other queries(Insert or Update).
For doing this in ZF2 you should get current db adapter and use it in all queries.

This code **will not work** correctly :

```
    $this->getAdapter()->getDriver()->getConnection()->beginTransaction();  
    //do some jobs - e.g : multiple tables update or insert.  
    $this->getAdapter()->getDriver()->getConnection()->rollback();
```

Since `$this->getAdapter()->getDriver()->getConnection()` Creates new db connection.

Use following code instead:

```
    $connection = $this->getAdapter()->getDriver()->getConnection();
    $connection->beginTransaction();
    //do some jobs - e.g : multiple tables update or insert. 
    $connection->rollback();
```

For check if your connections is correct , just enable query log in mysql.
After running query you will see connection number before each query in mysql log.Those must be same in all transaction queries.

Answer (score 0):

I used  `beginTransaction`, `rollback` and `commit` in controller.

where I performed number of transactions on different models where I using predefined functions without  any control transactions (not necessary for single DB transaction).

Using   `$this->getAdapter()->getDriver()->getConnection()->beginTransaction();`
gives error on `undefined getAdapter()` methods.

So I perform following way,

```
  //begain tarnsaction
                $db = Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getDefaultAdapter();

                $db->beginTransaction();

//rollback

                $db->rollback();

//commit db changes

                $db->commit();
```

Hope it may useful to solve problem.