# Is there support for multi-insertion in 1 query?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have products feeds and want to insert it in one query in ZF2. Is there any feature in ZF2 that make it easier?

My Blog : http://programming-tips.in

Comment: This may possibly help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831582/how-does-zend-db-in-zf2-control-transactions

Comment: Actually I have an array $products = array(0 => array(----),1 => array(----),....).I am looking for that is there any function in ZF2 which can take this array as input and insert into database at once.Right now I can run a loop and insert each record one by one using $this->insert($product_array);

Answer (score 0):

In ZF1, to allow this, I extended the Mysql Adapter and added an extendedInsert method.

Of course, the easier route is just to surround your inserts with a transaction/commit as commented above.  Shoving multiple inserts through in a single transaction is about the same as doing an extended insert as far as how much time it takes.  Plus, you should be able to use a prepared statement and just iterate through your array to insert all the records.